# How to reset or remove the gradient on the select element in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, customization

I need to completely remove or override specifically the gradient on the select element. I've downloaded a custom copy of Bootstrap, without the form components, and the select element appears the way i need, but everything else is obviously gone, and i only need to remove the select gradient.
Thanks.

Comment: In Bootstrap `<select>` doesn't have a gradient. Did you mean [button dropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)?

Comment: Please show us the css code for the select element from your custom Bootstrap example.

Comment: If the default glossy gradient look in Safari is meant, have a look here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638677/how-can-i-remove-the-gloss-on-a-select-element-in-safari-on-mac)

You may add this attribute to your css class:
`-webkit-appearance:none;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gradients will be on the `.btn-*` class (assuming you're using button dropdowns).

For example (with btn-primary):

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #006dcc;
  *background-color: #0044cc;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0044cc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0044cc);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #0044cc #0044cc #002a80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0044cc', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
```

To remove the gradient, you'd simply remove all the background properties (including the filters at the bottom) apart from `background-color;`:

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #006dcc;
  border-color: #0044cc #0044cc #002a80;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

You'd also want to finish up by using a single-color border:

```
.btn-primary {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #006dcc;
  border-color: #0044cc;
}
```

You'd also need to do the same for the .btn-*:hover, :focus and :active styles.

Answer (score 4):

Comment by *Herr_Hansen* works for me.

For Safari, try adding `-webkit-appearance:none;` to `<select>` with CSS

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found the gradient styles were in the bootstrap.theme.css I was loading with my other styles. Once I removed this file, all went back to normal.