# Browser (Webkit, IE, Firefox) Change background for select

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have been trying to get rid of the default gradient background in Website. I know if I set the -webkit-appereance:none this would be possible but then I will lose the arrows and other behaviors in the dropdown that I want. Is there anyway of setting the background to white with the -webkit-appearance: menulist ?

This is what I have but the background does not change

```
.ius select{
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    -moz-appearance: menulist;
    appearance: menulist;
    height:32px;
    border:1px solid #c8c8c8;
    width:250px;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to replace just the background without getting rid of a select's other features. You could always use a jQuery plugin like msDropDown to style a select however you want.

Answer (score 5):

The appearance property is generally used for two things:

1. Mimicking the native styling of other elements
2. OR removing all native styling (setting appearance to none)

It's a pretty weird property.

Since you want to remove the native default background, you need to set appearance to none. This will remove **all** styling (the gradients and the default arrow icons). This isn't a big deal however, since you can just use css to apply more styling to it.

With the markup:

```
<select id="menulist">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

And CSS:

```
#menulist {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid rgb(156,156,156);
    width:250px;
    text-indent: 8px;
    /**
    * replace this background url with a proper arrow asset
    **/
    background: url('http://placehold.it/5x10') no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
```

The full jsfiddle is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/vR53Q/2/

Since this property is only supported on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, I would probably go a different route and either use the native select styling or use a dropdown component that you have full control over.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Firefox. The browser renders its own dropdown on top of the background image.

Comment: It looks like there are 2 FF bugs related to this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605985 You can however, push the arrow out of the way using text-indent. It does look weird though, and you should ideally just not use the appearance property and create your own component instead.

Comment: FYI: I was able to use unicode ▲ and ▼ positioned on top of each other (instead of a background image) to recreate the arrows.  I did this in a <label> tag positioned on left side of the <select>.  Thought this might help.