# Dropdown style is different in Mac OS safari and windows safari browser

Tags: html, css, macos, drop-down-menu

I've been confused about the HTML dropdown  design style is differ in MAC OS and windows OS safari browser.

Is this expected native behavior style? Can we bring the windows dropdown style in MAC OS without using any javascript.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember all you have to do is add `-webkit-appearance:none;` to your dropdown class.

I refer to this post: [How can I remove the gloss on a select element in Safari on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638677/how-can-i-remove-the-gloss-on-a-select-element-in-safari-on-mac)

Comment: this will remove the arrow also