# How to get rid of white shadow on the background of select input dropdown in ios mobile according to css?

Tags: ios, css, media-queries

My question is about when i tried **-webkit-appearance:none**,the white shadow has disappered.
    However caret arrow in select box not display anymore.
    How should i resolved this please? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the gloss on a select element in Safari on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638677/how-can-i-remove-the-gloss-on-a-select-element-in-safari-on-mac)

Comment: i tried this but it seems not working.

Comment: Can you post a photo of what you want removed?