# Change background color of <select> on iOS

Tags: css

There are numerous answers here on SO for "how to style  elements" in Safari, e.g. [How can I remove the gloss on a select element in Safari on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638677/how-can-i-remove-the-gloss-on-a-select-element-in-safari-on-mac)

But none of them have allowed me to set `background-color` on iOS.

Is this just impossible? I have tried `-webkit-appearance: none` and that does not work on iOS; you can use this CodePen to test that it does not: https://codepen.io/jonmircha/pen/PEvqPa

Comment: Safari only allows the OS the privilege of determining the style of certain UI elements (scrollbars are another example). If it's critical to set the background colour you may have to implement your own select widget (e.g. `<div class="my-custom-selector">...</div>`)

Comment: Have you found out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. There are numerous differences when it comes to styling selects in different browser. Eg. In some browsers you can manipulate the caret, in others the surrounding color rules will affect the options text color, and the list goes on.

If you need a custom looking select that performs equal on all browser you will have to build a fake dropdown and couple it with the dropdown change event using js.

Comment: I understand that. My question still stands -- is it possible, or not, to change the background color of <select> elements in iOS using basic, plain CSS?