# How to change the colour of the show entries dropdown menu in DT package

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I noticed that in the DT package the show entries dropdown displays differently in Safari then Firefox. This is fine but we need to change the blue colour as it does not match the colour scheme of the app. I have used the web inspector/developer to look at the different CSS objects but was not able to determine what to change to update this item.

Does anyone know how to update the blue dropdown arrow within the button?

[image]

Comment: This SO reply could be useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764639/4821142](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764639/4821142)

Comment: You have to remove the default styling of dropdown and have to add your own. I am afraid there is no option to change the color in dropdown arrow in in safari.

Comment: Thank you @Till that solved the problem!